# determine whether in each of the following, if W is a subspace of V.

Tags: vector-spaces

i) W is all of the real functions that fulfill $f(1)$=$f(4)$

ii) W is all of the real even functions, which means $f(a)$=$f(-a)$

iii) W is all of the real functions that fulfill $f(7)$=3

please I want you to show how in each one we can decide according to the subspace definition requirements and show a detailed examples.

Comment: What is $V$ exactly?

Comment: Presumably it's the space of real functions, $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii), the answer is yes. Clearly the set of all even functions is nonempty; it contains the zero function $f(x) = 0$. The sum of two even functions is even because 
\begin{align}
\text{$f$ and $g$ are even} & \implies f(-x)=f(x) \text{ and } g(-x)=g(x) \\[0.1in]
& \implies (f+g)(-x) = f(-x)+g(-x) = f(x)+g(x) = (f+g)(x) \\[0.1in]
& \implies \text{$f+g$ is even}.
\end{align}
The product of an even function with any constant $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is even because
\begin{align}
\text{$f$ is even} & \implies f(-x)=f(x)  \\[0.1in]
& \implies (kf)(-x) = k\big(f(-x)\big) = k\big(f(x)\big) = (kf)(x) \\[0.1in]
& \implies \text{$kf$ is even}.
\end{align}

Similar arguments apply to (i), so it is also a subspace.

For (iii), it is not a subspace. You only need to find a counterexample, and you should give it a try. (It is very easy.)

Comment: thank you, this is a perfect explanation !!